# Is there another method that can replace .val(), I need to use another value to select a class

Tags: jquery

I need to create a string to select a class I've done this using .val() but I need another alternative since the value stored on the option tag I need has to be sent to a CRM database.

I've tried concatenating with data-* .text .attr() and other methods but it doesn´t work

This is the html:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" style='width:90%;height:30px;' name='LEADCF194' id="proyectos">
  <option value='-None-'>-Elige un proyecto-</option>
  <option value='Piemonti&#x20;Etapa&#x20;1&#x20;&#x28;Torre&#x20;1&#x20;y&#x20;2&#x29;'>Piemonti</option>
  <option value='villa_del_bosque'>Villa del Bosque Etapa 2</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">

                  <div id="piemonti" class="hidden bono piemonti">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="logo_project_bono">
                          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://descuentosferia.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/logo-piemonti-low.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 no_pad">
                        <div class="text_descuentos">
                          <div class="center">
                            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Gran Lanzamiento</h3>
                            <p style="text-align:center;">Marzo 1</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div id="villa_del_bosque" class="hidden bono villa_del_bosque">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="logo_project_bono">
                          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://descuentosferia.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/villa_bosque-low.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 no_pad">
                        <div class="text_descuentos">
                          <div class="center">
                            <h3>Últimos apartamentos Torre 1</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And this is the jquery:

```
$("#proyectos").change(function() {
  $(".bono").removeClass('hidden').addClass('hidden');
  $("." + $(this).val()).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

As you see, que jquery uses the change function to get the the select tag with id=proyectos, searches for a div with class=bono an uses the .val() method to select and hide the class=hidden for the selected option.

This works fine for the third option which has the value="villa_del_bosque", but I can't use that value since I need to pass a value like the one on the second option value="Piemonti Etapa 1 (Torre 1 y 2)"  to the CRM database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use index property of selected option and show the relative .bono div

```
$("#proyectos").change(function() {
    $(".bono:not('.hidden')").addClass('hidden');
    var index = $("#proyectos").prop('selectedIndex');
  $(".bono").eq(index-1).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Let me know if It works.

Best regards,
emanuele

Comment: You're welcome @CarlosA.Moreno . Thank you for your feedback. Could you confirm my answer like a solution, please?